# testing a download file link using JWebUnit

Tags: java, jwebunit

I am using JWebUnit. How can i use it to test if a download link works properly and the file is actually downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the header once the link is pressed getRequestHeaders() then use then get the returned source to evaluate.